# I'm trying to make loginform check using knex but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, forms, knex.js

**My Code:**

```
function checkLogIn() {
  var emailValue = document.getElementById("emails").value;
  var usernameValue = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var passwordValue = document.getElementById("password").value;

  knex("users").select("id").where({
    email: emailValue,
    username: usernameValue,
    password: passwordValue,
   });
}
```

It should takes values from HTML and compare HTML values with MySQL DB values.
I know that the code is not properly correct but since I didn't find anything about it, I was trying to test it a little bit. Does someone have any answer?

Comment: Can you try using it under try..catch and const user = knex("users"......
and log user ( in try ) and error ( in catch ) and check what error you're getting ?

Answer (score 0):

The `knex` function will return a promise and when that promise is fulfilled, either an empty array or an array of length 1.

To check if a user exists with the email, username, and password value they entered, try:

```
async function checkLogIn() {
  var email = document.getElementById("emails").value;
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

  var [user] = await knex("users").select("id").where({ email, username, password });
  return !!user
}
```

> Note that you should never store a password directly, instead store the bcrypt of the password, preferably with a salt.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would chime in with a modern version of an answer that doesn't leak out variables anywhere and utilizes the best of Knex :)

See the comments explaining the nuances of the code.

```
async function checkLogIn() { // make sure to put async in front of your function so it supports await
  
  // best to use const here to scope it only to this function 
  const email = document.getElementById('emails').value;
  const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
  const password = document.getElementById('password').value;

  const user = await knex('users')
                      .select('id')
                      .where({ email, username, password })
                      .first();
  // note that I chained the .first() to the query so that you only get the first match. 
  // Likely, your email and/or username fields are unique so that there can only be one result anyways

  return !!user // this bit returns a boolean (true/false) in case the user exist.
}
```